# Using proper language subtag for US audience

Tags: html, localization, internationalization

I used to think that if I want to target US audience I should use:

```html
<html lang=en_us>
```

However, recently I got this message from https://validator.w3.org

> Error: Bad value en_US for attribute lang on element html: The language subtag en_us is not a valid language subtag.

So is the `en_US` totally wrong? I should change all my html tags to `en` from `en_US` now?

Any detailed information on this?

Comment: It should be `en-US` not `en_us`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to use `en-US` not `en_US` I'm pretty sure.